# The cost of memory allocation in a loop in C

Tags: c, allocation

Is there a significant difference between allocating an array inside or outside a loop in terms of cost of time?

I use many arrays in functions inside a loop in my program, should I pass all the arrays as function parameters to increase the performance although it decreases the readability?  For example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 1000000
void foo()
{
    int* array = (int*)malloc(N*sizeof(int));
    /*
    Do something with the array
    */
    free(array);
}
int main()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<1000000; i++)
        foo();
    return 0;
}
```

or

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 1000000
void foo(int* array)
{
    /*
    Do something with the array
    */
}
int main()
{
    int i;
    int* array = (int*)malloc(N*sizeof(int));
    for(i=0; i<1000000; i++)
        foo(array);
    free(array);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that your second variant decreases readability.

Comment: It becomes 

__double sample(double* local_values, double* global_values, double* global_pos, double* local_pos, double* old_local_pos, double* new_local_pos, double* global_weight_array, double* global_weight_array, double_pair* pair_array, stack* stack_list, int array_size, int num_of_procs, int rank, const gsl_rng * r, MPI_Status* status, MPI_Datatype particle_type, MPI_Datatype double_pair_type)__

and also this function calls other several functions. I think decleration of an array just before using it is more readable.

Comment: Have you measured the time difference in the code?

Comment: It uses probabilistic algorithm, so I am not be able to measure it, that is the reason why I asked this question.

Comment: If it is only a readability issue, you could keep the pointers to the arrays in a struct and just pass a pointer to the struct to the functions.

Use a _deterministic pseudo random number generator_ with a constant seed to get _reproducible results_, instead of "real" random numbers -- at least for testing.

Comment: the first example will perform the malloc/free sequence 1000000 times.  The second example will perform the malloc/free sequence only 1 time.  So, naturally, the second example will execute MUCH faster than the first.  IMO: both examples have the same readability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cost of a memory allocation is not very dependent on the size of the allocation. Roughly speaking, a memory allocation of any size is O(1), and obviously standard libraries are optimized to make allocations as fast as possible.

So if you need a very big allocation, as in the example program, the cost of allocation will be trivial compared with the cost of initializing the allocated memory (to say nothing of the cost of actually doing the computation which is required).

For small allocations in very tight loops, where the allocation overhead might be noticeable, alternative mechanisms might be useful; one of these is the one suggested in the question, passing a preallocated array as an additional parameter to the function. (Other possibilities include using C's variable length arrays (VLAs), if they are available on all target platforms, or `alloca`/`_alloca`/`_malloca`.)

But I would suggest not implementing microoptimizations of this form until there is solid evidence that the time savings are justified; otherwise, the cost in maintainability and readability will outweigh any small time savings you might achieve.

Answer (score 2):

The second example is better with regards to time. Assuming the thing you would do with the array in 'foo' for each example is the same.

In the second example: You allocate one array, and do something to it a bunch of times. Then after you do that destroy it.

In the first example: each iteration of the loop you create a new array, do something and then destroy it. This means that extra time is taken to create and destroy the array each iteration of the loop.

Comment: This answer doesn't contain much that is not already present in the question.

Comment: I'm answering his question regards to time, which is yes. It does matter. The first variant is less efficient than the second. I've made that more clear.

Comment: Does it make significant change? Let's say N = e+8, the number of iterations is e+10 and foo performs a matrix multiplication with the array.

Comment: As noted by rici, it is unlikely to actually be that much different. There IS indeed a difference but it's a trivial amount of time compared to the time spent doing the matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

Declaring the array and then using it strikes me as the better way to do things.

Your declaration takes place in a higher-level body of code and happens once: therefore it is easy to understand what is going on, change the allocation size, handle allocation errors, and debug.

Declaring the array in the for loop raises a definite [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) for me: it is a solution that lacks modularity.