# P/Invoke C++ DLL for filling a managed buffer

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, marshalling

Basically I have a DLL and a header file (C++) for a data acquisition device that I use for my research. The device has 8 sensors and each sensor has x,y,z,etc data points. I'd like to create a UI program in WPF for this device. So far I've successfully been able to communicate with the device in .NET via an unsafe code implementation and read data into an array of structs (where each struct corresponds to one of the sensors). However I'd like to see if I can get it working with a strictly safe code implementation, but I've just been hitting brick walls for a while now. This is my first time working with unmanaged vs. managed code so please bear with me. I've searched countless threads online and the rabbit hole just keeps getting deeper so I'd like some advice from someone with experience. Basically the API header file has a function with the following definition:

```
int GetSynchronousRecord(USHORT sensorID, void *pRecord, int recordSize);
```

Essentially we pass the function a buffer by reference, and it fills it up. I have the option of getting either a single sensor's data, or all sensors at once depending on the sensorID argument I pass. What **HAS** worked for me so far (in the managed world) is if I do the following:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct DOUBLE_POSITION_ANGLES_TIME_Q_RECORD
{
    public double x;     
    public double y; 
    public double z;  
    public double a; 
    public double e;    
    public double r;     
    public double time;
    public ushort quality;
};  

...

[DllImport("ATC3DG64.DLL", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int GetSynchronousRecord(ushort sensorID, ref DOUBLE_POSITION_ANGLES_TIME_Q_RECORD record, int recordSize);

...

DOUBLE_POSITION_ANGLES_TIME_Q_RECORD record = new DOUBLE_POSITION_ANGLES_TIME_Q_RECORD();
// Get the data from SENSOR_1 only
errorCode = GetSynchronousRecord(1, ref record, Marshal.SizeOf(record));
```

So this implementation works fine, I can get all the coordinate data and at a really good speed. However, I'd like to get ALL the sensors at once. In the C++ API code samples, they pass the **GetSynchronousRecord** function an ARRAY of STRUCTS, one struct for each sensor. I tried to do the same in C# as follows:

```
[DllImport("ATC3DG64.DLL", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int GetSynchronousRecord(ushort sensorID, ref DOUBLE_POSITION_ANGLES_TIME_Q_RECORD[] record, int recordSize);

// Define Array of Struct for each sensor
DOUBLE_POSITION_ANGLES_TIME_Q_RECORD[] record = new DOUBLE_POSITION_ANGLES_TIME_Q_RECORD[8];
while(recording) {
...
// Get data from ALL sensors (0xffff)
errorCode = GetSynchronousRecord(0xffff, ref record, Marshal.SizeOf(record)*8);
...
}
```

But this straight up crashes my program with an System.ExecutionEngineException error. I've read that since my function is expecting a void* pointer, that I should use an **IntPtr** argument, but this approach seemed quite confusing to be honest. Another thing I tried is to actually loop over each sensor and call the function for the sensor, but this dropped the speed INSANELY almost to 1 record/second (instead of 100 records/second). Many other similar threads on stackexchange say to use `out` parameter, or to use [In, Out] attribute on the function definition, but none of these suggestions worked.

**TL;DR:** If I understand my situation correctly, I have a MANAGED array of structs that I need to correctly pass to a C++ function as an argument (pass by reference), and then the function will fill my structs with data from a data acquisition device.

I apologize for the wall of text/code, any information for me from someone with experience would be much appreciated.

EDIT: Just to clarify, the GetSynchronousRecord function is INSIDE a while loop where on each iteration I'm getting new data points for each struct.

Comment: Any managed "pointer" must be `fixed` in order for the GC not to move it during the execution of the native part
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/fixed-statement

Comment: Thanks Sasha, but I'm not sure where in my code that is relevant, isn't `fixed` used only in an unsafe context? I don't think I have a need for unsafe code.

Comment: You didn't show the version of your pinvoke that changes the second argument to be an array passed by ref. That's the mistake. Easy to fix, but I won't answer until the question is complete.

Comment: @David Heffernan Sorry I didn't include it for brevity but I've updated the code to show the P/Invoke argument in the case of using an array, I hope this is what you meant. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second p/invoke declaration is wrong. You had

```
[DllImport("ATC3DG64.DLL", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int GetSynchronousRecord(
    ushort sensorID, 
    ref DOUBLE_POSITION_ANGLES_TIME_Q_RECORD[] record, 
    int recordSize
);
```

The problem is the array parameter. Because you pass that array by `ref` that actually makes it a double pointer. Instead you want to simply remove the `ref` and declare the import like so:

```
[DllImport("ATC3DG64.DLL", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int GetSynchronousRecord(
    ushort sensorID, 
    [Out] DOUBLE_POSITION_ANGLES_TIME_Q_RECORD[] record, 
    int recordSize
);
```

The `[Out]` attribute tells the marshaler that the data is flowing out of the function. Without it the default assumption is that the data flows in.

When you call the function do so like this:

```
errorCode = GetSynchronousRecord(0xffff, record, Marshal.SizeOf(record)*record.Length);
```

Comment: Just one small correction, I had to add an [Out] attribute on the records parameter in the function declaration like so:


    `[DllImport("ATC3DG64.DLL", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]`
    `public static extern int GetSynchronousRecord(ushort sensorID, [Out] DOUBLE_POSITION_ANGLES_TIME_Q_RECORD[] records, int recordSize);`



But otherwise its working great. Thank you very much!

Comment: That surprises me. Does your actual record type contain other fields that make it non blittable.

Comment: I mean the record type is the `DOUBLE_POSITION_ANGLES_TIME_Q_RECORD` struct, which can be seen in my initial post. I don't think any of those fields are non blittable. Its just `double` and `ushort`.

Answer (score -1):

The best way is probably using `IntPtr` rather than `ref DOUBLE_POSITION_ANGLES_TIME_Q_RECORD`.

I'd change the P/Invoke signature to:

```
[DllImport("ATC3DG64.DLL", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int GetSynchronousRecord(ushort sensorID, IntPtr record, int recordSize);
```

Create an IntPtr that points to the needed memory space:

```
IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf<DOUBLE_POSITION_ANGLES_TIME_Q_RECORD>() * 8);
```

Call the P/Invoke function (which should fill the memory with the structs):

```
errorCode = GetSynchronousRecord(0xffff, ptr, Marshal.SizeOf<DOUBLE_POSITION_ANGLES_TIME_Q_RECORD>() * 8);
```

Get the structures from the memory block:

```
DOUBLE_POSITION_ANGLES_TIME_Q_RECORD[] records = new DOUBLE_POSITION_ANGLES_TIME_Q_RECORD[8];
for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
     records[i] = Marshal.PtrToStructure<DOUBLE_POSITION_ANGLES_TIME_Q_RECORD>(IntPtr.Add(ptr, i * Marshal.SizeOf<DOUBLE_POSITION_ANGLES_TIME_Q_RECORD>()));
}
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
```

Comment: One should also free the allocated memory by calling `Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr)` (ideally in a `finally` block to avoid memory leaks if an exception occurs) after the allocated data was transferred to managed memory, i.e. after the record array was filled.

Comment: Thank you, this makes a lot of sense. I'm not sure if I can ask a follow up question here? So the `GetSynchronousRecord` function is actually inside a loop to continuously get data. Would I have to free the `ptr` memory on EACH loop iteration, or will the old data be overwritten by new data on each iteration (and then I can free the `ptr` after once acquisition has terminated) ?

Comment: @LittleFinger From how you described the ``GetSynchronousRecord `` function, no, it wouldn't be in a for loop. It's only after the ``GetSynchronousRecord `` function is called, you loop through to get each structure and then free it after the looping is done (which I've updated in the answer)

Comment: @ub3rst4r Sorry what I meant was, all of that code is inside a while loop, because I need to continuously get all 8 sensor data. Inside each `while` loop iteration, I understand that I need the `for` loop to go over each structure. But my question is will I have to allocate and free an IntPtr on each `while` loop iteration?

Comment: @LittleFinger As [this answer explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28919763/533242), there is no changes in cost whether it's outside or inside the loop. If you're doing many small allocations then having the memory allocated outside the loop maybe better.

Comment: No, this is not the best way. This is the worst way. It's easy to do this without any manual allocations.

Comment: Just want to comment that this approach worked as well and I tested it on 1000 records. Both this answer and David Heffernan's answer ran for a similar amount of time however David's answer requires less lines of code and so I'll mark it as the accepted answer. But I really appreciate this answer because it showed me a concrete example of how I can use IntPtr which I was confused about previously, so thank you @ub3rst4r !